# how to sort a txt file in specific order in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have this first text for example

```
today is sunny in the LA 
and the temperature is 21C

today is cloudy in the NY 
and the temperature is 18C

today is sunny in the DC 
and the temperature is 25C
```

and this is the order I want:

```
18C 
25C
21C
```

I want to change the first file to be the same order as the second one but without deleting anything:

```
today is cloudy in the NY
and the temperature is 18C

today is sunny in the DC 
and the temperature is 25C

today is sunny in the LA
and the temperature is 21C
```

Comment: next time, post the code you created and tried for review. That's the way you will learn the most and fastest

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: The PSv3+ solution below answers a *different* question: it sorts the paragraphs *numerically* by the temperature values contained in them, not in an *externally prescribed* order.

- As such, it may still be of interest, given the question's generic title.
- For an answer to the question *as asked*, see [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52349314/45375).

---

Here's a concise solution, but note that it requires reading the input file into memory as a whole (in any event, `Sort-Object` collects its input objects all in memory as well, since it does not use temporary files to ease potential memory pressure):

```
((Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -split '\r?\n\r?\n' -replace '\r?\n$' |
  Sort-Object { [int] ($_ -replace '(?s).+ (\d+)C$', '$1') }) -join 
    [Environment]::NewLine * 2
```

- `(Get-Content -Raw file.txt)` reads the input file into memory as a whole, as a single, multi-line string.
- `-split '\r?\n\r?\n'` breaks the multi-line string into an array of paragraphs (blocks of lines separated by an empty line), and `-replace '\r?\n$'` removes a trailing newline, if any, from the paragraph at the very end of the file.

  - Regex `\r?\n` matches both Windows-style CRLF and Unix-style LF-only newlines.
- `Sort-Object { [int] ($_ -replace '(?s).+ (\d+)C$', '$1') })` numerically sorts the paragraphs by the temperature number at the end of each paragraph (e.g. `18`).

  - `$_` represents the input paragraph at hand.
  - `-replace '...', '...'` performs string replacement based on a regex, which in this case extracts the temperature number string from the end of the paragraph.

    - See [`Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) for information about regexes (regular expressions) and [`Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator) for information about the `-replace` operator.
  - Cast `[int]` converts the number string to an integer for proper numerical sorting.
- `-join [Environment]::NewLine * 2` reassembles the sorted paragraphs into a single multi-line string, with paragraphs separated by an empty line.

  - `[Environment]::NewLine` is the platform-appropriate newline sequence; you can alternatively hard-code newlines as `` "`r`n" `` (CRLF) or `` "`n" `` (LF).

You can send the output to a new file by appending something like
`... | Set-Content sortedFile.txt` (which makes the file "ANSI"-encoded in Windows PowerShell, and UTF-8-encoded in PowerShell *Core* by default; use `-Encoding` as needed).

Since the entire input file is read into memory up front, it *is* possible to write the results directly back to the input file (`... | Set-Content file.txt`), but doing so bears the slight risk of data loss, namely if writing is interrupted before completion.

Answer (score 1):

[Nas' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52346839/45375) works, but it is an O(m*n) operation; that is, with m paragraphs to output in prescribed order and n input paragraphs, m * n operations are required; if *all* input paragraphs are to be output (in the prescribed order), i.e, if m equals n, the effort is *quadratic*.

The following PSv4+ solution will scale better, as it only requires *linear* rather than *quadratic* effort:

```
# The tokens prescribing the sort order, which may come from 
# another file read with Get-Content, for instance.
$tokensToSortBy = '18C', '25C', '21C'

# Create a hashtable that indexes the input file's paragraphs by the sort
# token embedded in each.
((Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -split '\r?\n\r?\n' -replace '\r?\n$').ForEach({
  $htParagraphsBySortToken[$_ -replace '(?s).* (\d+C)$(?:\r?\n)?', '$1'] = $_
})

# Loop over the tokens prescribing the sort order, and retrieve the
# corresponding paragraph, then reassemble the paragraphs into a single,
# multi-line string with -join
$tokensToSortBy.ForEach({ $htParagraphsBySortToken[$_] }) -join [Environment]::NewLine * 2
```

- `(Get-Content -Raw file.txt)` reads the input file into memory as a whole, as a single, multi-line string.
- `-split '\r?\n\r?\n'` breaks the multi-line string into an array of paragraphs (blocks of lines separated by an empty line), and `-replace '\r?\n$'` removes a trailing newline, if any, from the paragraph at the very end of the file.

  - Regex `\r?\n` matches both Windows-style CRLF and Unix-style LF-only newlines.
- `$_ -replace '(?s).* (\d+C)$(?:\r?\n)?', '$1'` extracts the sort token (e.g., `25C`) from each paragraph, which becomes the hashtable's key.

  - `$_` represents the input paragraph at hand.
  - `-replace '...', '...'` performs string replacement based on a regex.

    - See [`Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) for information about regexes (regular expressions) and [`Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator) for information about the `-replace` operator.
- `-join [Environment]::NewLine * 2` reassembles the sorted paragraphs into a single multi-line string, with paragraphs separated by an empty line.

  - `[Environment]::NewLine` is the platform-appropriate newline sequence; you can alternatively hard-code newlines as `` "`r`n" `` (CRLF) or `` "`n" `` (LF).

You can send the output to a new file by appending something like
`... | Set-Content sortedFile.txt` to the last statement (which makes the file "ANSI"-encoded in Windows PowerShell, and UTF-8-encoded in PowerShell *Core* by default; use `-Encoding` as needed).

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = Get-Content -path C:\text.txt
$order = '18C','25C','21C'

foreach ($item in $order)
{
    $text | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match "$item`$") { # `$ to match string at the end of the line
            Write-Output $text[($_.ReadCount-2)..($_.ReadCount)] # output lines before and after match
        }
    }
}
```