# What is the difference between Env: and [System.Environment]?

Tags: powershell

Given @mklement's good answer in [how to sort a txt file in specific order in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52346425/how-to-sort-a-txt-file-in-specific-order-in-powershell#52347418), it made me wonder...

What is the difference between `Env:` and `[System.Environment]`?

Why is `[Environment]::NewLine` available, but `$Env:NewLine` does not exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`[System.Environment]` is the .Net framework's static environment class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment?view=netframework-4.7.2). It offers static methods related to the "environment" including ways to get environment variables.

`$env:WHATEVER` is special variable syntax whereby you can access the contents of a PSProvider using variable semantics.

[What is a PSProvider?](https://superuser.com/q/1065812/355415) (also see [about_Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-6))

It's basically a way to access hierarchical data stores through a singular interface that is similar to a filesystem.

In fact `FileSystem` is itself a PSProvider in PowerShell, and this is why cmdlets that deal with files don't mention files (i.e.: `Get-ChildItem`, `Get-Content`, `Set-Location`, etc.).

To see available providers, use [`Get-PSProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psprovider?view=powershell-6):

> ```
> Name                 Capabilities                                                Drives                                                     
> ----                 ------------                                                ------                                                     
> Registry             ShouldProcess, Transactions                                 {HKLM, HKCU}                                               
> Alias                ShouldProcess                                               {Alias}                                                    
> Environment          ShouldProcess                                               {Env}                                                      
> FileSystem           Filter, ShouldProcess, Credentials                          {A, C, D, P...}                                            
> Function             ShouldProcess                                               {Function}                                                 
> Variable             ShouldProcess                                               {Variable}                                                 
> Certificate          ShouldProcess                                               {Cert}                                                     
> WSMan                Credentials                                                 {WSMan}
> ```

Use [`Get-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psdrive?view=powershell-6) to just see the drives themselves:

> ```
> Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                   
> ----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                   
> A                 103.23         46.58 FileSystem    A:\                    
> Alias                                  Alias                                
> C                 200.02         22.77 FileSystem    C:\                    
> Cert                                   Certificate   \                      
> D                1048.88       2677.13 FileSystem    D:\                    
> Env                                    Environment                          
> Function                               Function                             
> HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER      
> HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE     
> O                  49.34         10.16 FileSystem    O:\                    
> P                 335.32        176.50 FileSystem    P:\                    
> S                                      FileSystem    S:\                    
> Variable                               Variable                             
> WSMan                                  WSMan
> ```

`Environment` is also a PSProvider, which you can see by trying to navigate to its PSDrive:

```
Set-Location Env:
```

Or browsing it:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

Or even getting its contents:

```
Get-Content Env:\COMPUTERNAME
Get-ChildItem Env: | Get-Content
```

The special variable syntax is a shorthand way of accessing certain PSProviders (they don't all support it), and it's most often used with Environment (I'd venture a guess that syntax was created specifically for the Environment).

That syntax does actually work for the file system but it's pretty awkward

```
${C:\users\briantist\test.txt}
```

Tab completion doesn't work correctly with that syntax.

If you try it for something like the registry provider, it will tab complete but throw an exception about it not being implemented when you run it.

Here's a fun useless one: use the `Variable:\` provider:

```
$test = 'test'
$Variable:test
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. I note that `(Get-PSProvider).Drives` and `Get-PSDrive` appear to produce the same output. Why does .Net have [Environment]::NewLine and the PowerShell Environment provider does not have it?

Comment: @lit the `[Environment]` has a wider scope. It deals with more than just the _variables_ part of the environment. The provider is only for environment variables. For that matter you could ask why the environment provider is missing `::Is64BitOperatingSystem` or the `::FailFast()` method. It's just outside the scope of environment _variables_ which is all that the provider was meant to expose.

Comment: Note that `$Variable:test` does not reference `Variable:` drive, but it is directly recognized as reference to variable. For example `${variable:C:\users\briantist\test.txt}` will reference variable with name `C:\users\briantist\test.txt`, but not file; `$variable:local:test` will reference variable with name `local:test`, but not variable `test` in `local` scope.

Comment: Very interesting @PetSerAl !

Comment: The name of the feature is _namespace notation_, though I don't think it's in the official docs. Only those providers that implement the `IContentCmdletProvider` interface support it, because `${<drive>:<path>}` is essentially the same as `Get-Content -Path <drive>:<path>` - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2268#issuecomment-283755725 and https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7770#issuecomment-421219699. For the filesystem it is currently broken on Unix (PS Core) - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3245

Comment: Great stuff as usual @mklement0 , very valuable info. I will edit it into the answer when I get a chance (or feel free to edit it in sooner if you have a moment)